# javascript function inside jquery response not working

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Calling a JavaScript function returned from a Ajax response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510779/calling-a-javascript-function-returned-from-a-ajax-response)

```
var url = "showpdf.php";
$.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: url,
    data:    {academic:academic,uni:uni,course:course,lan:lan,sem:sem,subject:subject,type:type,clz:clz},
    success: function(response)
    {
        alert(response);
        document.getElementById("alldata").innerHTML = response;

    }
});
```

inside response i have bellow html code with simple JavaScript function

```
<label onclick="popup()"> clickme </label>
<script>
function popup()
{
  alert("hello");
}
</script>
```

here, this popup()function is not working please help me.

Comment: take a look at:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/510779/calling-a-javascript-function-returned-from-a-ajax-response

Comment: ya i also tried this eval(document.getElementById("alldata").innerHTML = response);

but still its not working :(

Comment: no i didn't got any error.. .but that javascript function not working even if i used eval

Comment: `eval()` won't work with the raw response because it contains HTML, eval will only accept the Javascript content.

Comment: but in response i have both html as well as javascript code so why my javascript function is not working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you expect that Javascript contained within an ajax response is executed. This isn't the case, the browser doesn't execute any Javascript contained within ajax responses. It might be possible to try to parse out the Javascript and execute it in some way, such as `eval()` but that would be nasty and not a good idea. Using `eval()` you also have to consider that it will only accept valid Javascript, so you couldn't just pass your response to it because that includes some HTML.

A possible solution could be to have the `popup()` function already defined in the page or an external Javascript file, and to assign the click handler after you add the HTML to the DOM.

For example:

```
function popup()
{
    alert(this.id);
}


document.getElementById("alldata").innerHTML = response;
document.getElementById("myNewLabel").onclick = popup;
```

Comment: hii, i implemented same thing which you told, but i got one problem , i want to pass id of label in popup function so how to do that?

i tried like document.getElementById("myNewLabel").onclick = popup(this.id); but its not working :(

Comment: You don't need to pass the ID, just use `this.id` within the popup function.

Comment: ya its working .. :) thanks MrCode

Answer (score 0):

Make that string hidden in your page and just display it on success. like:

```
<label onclick="popup()" id="mylable" style="display:none"> clickme </label>
<script>
function popup()
{
  alert("hello");
}
</script>


var url = "showpdf.php";
$.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: url,
    data:    {academic:academic,uni:uni,course:course,lan:lan,sem:sem,subject:subject,type:type,clz:clz},
    success: function(response)
    {
       // alert(response);
        $("#mylable").show();

    }
});
```

Better way to try with DOM. Let me know if above code is work for you.

Comment: hey but 

<label onclick="popup()" id="mylable" style="display:none"> clickme </label>
<script>
function popup()
{
  alert("hello");
}
</script> this code i wrote in another file, so $("#mylable").show(); will not work der in jquery function

Comment: Keep the HTML code on same page form where you are calling the ajax function and echo something like "click"/ notclick in showpdf.php file. Check the response in success function if it is click  $("#mylable").show().

Comment: i couldn't understand what u r saying