# How To Execute JavaScript Code

Tags: javascript

How to Execute JavaScript Code Loaded using Ajax.

Like If We Are Loading JavaScript Code From Server Using JavaScript.

Edited:
       **I Don't Want To Script Tag To Interpret JavaScript Code. I'm Not Using jQuery And Any Other JavaScript Library To Do This. And I Don't Want To Invoke Any Already User-Defined Function.**

***I Simply Wants To Interpret The JavaScript Code Loaded From Server Using Ajax request.***

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/510779/calling-a-javascript-function-returned-from-an-ajax-response

Answer (score 2):

You may dynamically create an script element which has a src links to the Javascript code from serverside and insert it into the DOM tree manually.

```
// to create an script element.
var elemJS=document.createElement('script');

// set its src attribute to the js code from serverside
elemJS.src="http://aa.bb.cc/somescript.js";

// to find the head element.
var elemHead=document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];

// make the script element a child node of head
elemHead.appendChild(elemJS);

// Then enjoy your serverside code
```

Answer (score 0):

use eval(). You have to give an ID to your script:

```
<script id='ajax_script'>
    //your javascript code
</script>
```

And then after loading your ajax response, for loading the script you add this line:

```
eval(document.getElementById('ajax_script').innerHTML);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript's eval function. [Directly](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_eval.asp) or through e.g. [JQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.globalEval/):

```
jQuery.globalEval("var newVar = true;")
```