# script within a php page not executed when called using ajax

Tags: php, ajax

Please read below my scenario…
I have a PHP file wherein I have javascript within it..

```
 <?php
   echo ‘<script>’;
   echo ‘window.alert(“hi”)’;
   echo ‘</script>’;

 ?>
```

On execution of this file directly, the content inside the script is executed as expected. But if this same page is being called via ajax from another page, the script part is NOT executed.
Can you please let me know the possible reasons.
(note: I’m in a compulsion to have script within php page).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Executing <script> inside <div> retrieved by AJAX](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4619668/executing-script-inside-div-retrieved-by-ajax) or [Can scripts be inserted with innerHTML?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197575/can-scripts-be-inserted-with-innerhtml)

Comment: There is also this one too: [Calling a javascript function returned from an ajax response](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/510779/calling-a-javascript-function-returned-from-an-ajax-response)

Answer (score 1):

When you do an AJAX call you just grab the content from that page. JavaScript treats it as a string (not code). You would have to add the content from the page to your DOM in your AJAX callback.

```
$.get('/alertscript.php', {}, function(results){
    $("html").append(results);
});
```

Make sure you change the code to fit your needs. I'm supposing you use jQuery...

## Edited version

```
load('/alertscript.php', function(xhr) {    
    var result = xhr.responseText;  

    // Execute the code
    eval( result ); 

});



function load(url, callback) {
    var xhr;

    if(typeof XMLHttpRequest !== 'undefined') xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    else {
        var versions = ["MSXML2.XmlHttp.5.0", 
            "MSXML2.XmlHttp.4.0",
            "MSXML2.XmlHttp.3.0", 
            "MSXML2.XmlHttp.2.0",
            "Microsoft.XmlHttp"]

        for(var i = 0, len = versions.length; i < len; i++) {
        try {
            xhr = new ActiveXObject(versions[i]);
            break;
        }
            catch(e){}
        } // end for
    }

    xhr.onreadystatechange = ensureReadiness;

    function ensureReadiness() {
        if(xhr.readyState < 4) {
            return;
        }

        if(xhr.status !== 200) {
            return;
        }

        // all is well  
        if(xhr.readyState === 4) {
            callback(xhr);
        }           
    }

    xhr.open('GET', url, true);
    xhr.send('');
}
```

Comment: i'm using javascript ajax call... not jquery ajax.. :(

Comment: If you are just using XHR objects then its just a little bit more complex, but still remains the same.

Comment: xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
            alert(xhr.responseText);
        }
    }

Comment: thanks a lot @justin..
but am not clear with xhr objects. i use the normal ajax call given in link http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/tryit.asp?filename=tryajax_first

Comment: If you remove the <script> tags from the php script you can run eval() in JavaScript to run the code dynamically after your callback is complete. Or you can add it to the DOM. either way will work.

Comment: do you have any example that i can follow.. that would help me a lot to understand better.. thanks!