# execute script on ajax success

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

here is my javascript code in my php document:-

```
 ( function() {
if (window.CHITIKA === undefined) { window.CHITIKA = { 'units' : [] }; };
var unit = {"calltype":"async[2]","publisher":"soodsidhant","width":728,"height":90,"sid":"Chitika Default"};
var placement_id = window.CHITIKA.units.length;
window.CHITIKA.units.push(unit);
document.write('<div id="chitikaAdBlock-' + placement_id + '"></div>');
   }());
```

this javascript makes a div on loading just below where the script is placed.

and i have a separate x.js file which sends data through ajax...
i want to execute the above code when get success.

one more thing if this script is executed from x.js where will it create the div in my site??? Also am i able to change that position???

i had already tried :- giving the script tag in my php document an id="ads" as [[ answered here ]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510779/calling-a-javascript-function-returned-from-an-ajax-response) and calling it in ajax success by

```
eval(document.getElementById("ads").innerHTML);
```

and it didn't helped also with this method there was no error in console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this function in your file with the ajax request and then call it in the `.succuess(...)` callback from POST or PUT or whatever.

Comment: thanks, it worked and plz can you upvote this question, it is already graving my reputation. thanks for your help