# RAILS not rendering js.erb

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-5

Here is the workflow:

Starts with root_page.js

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function (data) {
    // code
};
httpRequest.open('GET', '/contents/ajax_rss.js', true);
httpRequest.send();
})
```

This sends ajax request which is successfully routed to contents#ajax_rss

```
def ajax_rss
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js {
    }
  end
end
```

And should render the following ajax_rss.js.erb

```
document.getElementById("rss").innerHTML = "HELLO WORLD!";
```

Here's the server response:

```
Processing by ContentsController#ajax_rss as JS
User Load (0.9ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? 
ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Rendering contents/ajax_rss.js.erb
Rendered contents/ajax_rss.js.erb (1.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 9ms (Views: 5.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.9ms)
```

But the text is not displayed accordingly. What am I missing? This is my first attempt at AJAX when not called from a form or button using remote: true.

All remote: true calls work as expected.

Comment: did you try this in browser console `document.getElementById("rss").innerHTML = "HELLO WORLD!";` and confirm that it is working ?

Comment: I did indeed....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using eval:

```
  request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.onreadystatechange = function()
  {
      if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200)
      {
          eval(request.responseText);
      }
  };
  request.open('GET', '/contents/ajax_rss.js');
  request.send();
```

Comment: Cheers Vijay. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

`remote: true` option enables client side to execute the js returned from the server.This is the part you need to fix.

You can pass the response to `eval(response)`.
Refer: [Calling a JavaScript function returned from an Ajax response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510779/calling-a-javascript-function-returned-from-an-ajax-response)