# AJAX js from the loaded part of the page doesn't work

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm using vanilla Ajax. I've just loaded the second html page via the first one. In the second one, there are two rows of "script src". No one of it has been loaded. Is there any reason for that?

```
function loadPage(url) 
{
    let Request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    let content = document.getElementsByTagName('main')[0];

    Request.onreadystatechange = () => {
        if (Request.readyState == 4 && Request.status == 200) {
            content.innerHTML = Request.responseText;
        }
        else if (!Request) {
            alert('Lalala');
        }
    }

    Request.open('GET', url);
    Request.send();
}
```

P.S. Please, advise me resolve without JQuery. THANKS!

Comment: Show second page too.

Comment: there is nothing interesting in it. its structure is:

Comment: <head> <div> <script>

Comment: everything is without html tag

Comment: When you append HTML to element, no JS will auto-execute there [Calling a JavaScript function returned from an Ajax response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510779/calling-a-javascript-function-returned-from-an-ajax-response)