# Module architecture with Vue.js - loading components as ajax

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, vuejs2, vue-component

I have an application that uses module (extension) system to widen its functionality. You can think of it as a report system, where each report type can be added later by providing some files that are copied to the server.

Now each report has a view screen and it can be different for each report type. This is both html + javascript + external javascript dependencies.

Can I design this behavior somehow with vue.js? The naive approach was to load the content as AJAX, and then bind it with `v-html`. I can also execute scripts inside with `eval(document.getElementById('scriptId').innerHTML);` as mentioned in [Calling a JavaScript function returned from an Ajax response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510779/calling-a-javascript-function-returned-from-an-ajax-response) answer. But this is not enough, as each module can contain references to additional javascript files.

What I would consider the best approach:

- From AJAX server side I have a controller that returns the contents of `.vue` file both `template` and `script` parts.
- From AJAX client side I have `$http` call that gets the contents of the response from above, parses it as a component and adds to DOM, executing all the scripts and a proper vue.js lifecycle.

Please note that normal dynamic components for vue.js, at least as they are described in the manual, do not work - it requires you to know the list of all possible components in advance, and `require` all of them (you can't `require` dynamically)