# How to add script tags received in AJAX response

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am receiving an HTML snippet from an AJAX request. The HTML contains some script tags as well, but when I add that HTML to a DOM element using JQuery, the script tags are not being added to the DOM. Rest of the elements gets added well. Here is a sample of what I receive:

```
<div>
<h1>Hello World!</h1>
<script type="text/javascript">{Some JS}</script>
</div>
```

When I add this to the DOM, the script tags are not added.

**EDIT**
I think it would be better to provide explanation for down-voting so people can know what to care of in future.
Anyway, Thank you all for your help. My issue was a little different where I receive not only the script but some HTML as well and I was wondering why the  tags does not gets added under the DOM to which I append this HTML response. I used some of the answers for script tags with src and below code for script tags with embedded code

```
var result = $(response); 
    $('#contentdiv').html(result.html());
    result.filter('script').each(function(){
        $.globalEval(this.text || this.textContent || this.innerHTML || '');
    });
```

Also I found a nice article about that
http://blog.gauffin.org/2015/07/embedded-script-tags-in-content-loaded-through-ajax-and-execute-the-script-tags-dynamically/

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this following:

```
<script>
        var src = 'response.js';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; 
        s.parentNode.insertBefore(src, s);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
var data = jQuery(xhr.responseText).not('script');
var scripts = jQuery(xhr.responseText).filter('script');
//Your logic to append ajax response to specific node in DOM
jQuery(scripts).appendTo('body');
```

You can refer to the following post [Calling a JavaScript function returned from an Ajax response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510779/calling-a-javascript-function-returned-from-an-ajax-response) for executing internal script

Answer (score 0):

this is how you can achieve this

```
document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('script')).src=response.src;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is much simpler code:

```
let the_script_el = $('<script>').html('alert("testing");');
$('body').append(the_script_el);
```

Check out this fiddle for your ease: http://jsfiddle.net/syamsoul/e7jdp5av/

Answer (score 0):

```
window.onload = function() {
var s = document.createElement('script');
s.type = 'text/javascript';
var code = 'alert("hello world!");';
try {
  s.appendChild(document.createTextNode(code));
  document.body.appendChild(s);
}
catch (e) {
  s.text = code;
  document.body.appendChild(s);
}
}
```